# Does a recovery drive needs updates?

Tags: windows-8, boot

I bought a PC with Windows 8 installed. Later I upgraded to Windows 8.1 and made a recovery drive on an USB pendrive.

Since then Windows 8.1 has got many new files with new updates.

1. If ever I cannot boot normally & I boot from the recovery pendrive, would I get back to a recent Windows 8.1? Or I would go back to the initial Windows 8?
2. It is then useful to do a new a new recovery drive, say every 6 months?

Comment: No; Your system would be repaired and restored based on the recovery image you provide. I see no use to update the recovery image when Windows Update can easily be ran. Of course I also create full images that can be restored to any hardware  I want.

Comment: I do not find your reply clear. so if I use a recovery image made in an USB on 1 April 2014, If I ever need to boot from this USB my pc will entirely be as it was on 1 April 2014?the PC

Comment: What part do you find not clear?  I don't see where I say anything that could be taken multiple ways.

Comment: For a pc bought in 2013 with windows 8. upgraded to windows 8.1 in 2013. recovery USB (system image) done 1st April 2014. If I need to boot on this USB, my PC will be again exactly as it was on 1sq April 2014?

Comment: Your system image will be compared to that image done on April 2014 nothing else will change. This means you will have to install any updates again.